# Oozie Shell Action params with single quotes getting dropped

Tags: shell, hadoop, mapreduce, oozie, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to run a **Oozie Shell Action** Job, via means of some sub-workflow configuration.

While writing the configuration file (`workflow.xml`), I wrap some variables (coming from a `job.properties` file), with single quotes, as:

```
<property>
    <name>myVar</name>
    <value>'${myVar}'</value>
</property>
```

However, in Shell script, the parameter received **does not** have any single quote ?  Any ideas ?

Answer (score -1):

Try without quotes. 
     
        myVar
        ${myVar}

Comment: I need those single quotes.

Comment: this can be a comment